# How to install redmine with apt without any prompt

Tags: debian, chef-infra, redmine, apt

I want to install Redmine with Chef.

When I run `apt-get install` by hand it prompt multiple dialog in order to configure the database. Mainly how to connect to it (type (sqlite or mysql), socket, name, password ...).

How can I give all this configuration without having all this dialog to answer?

Comment: Have you try some of the cookbooks that  are ready for this?

Comment: There seems not maintained anymore :/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq install redmin
```

This will answer all questions default.

Comment: Is there a way to configure the answer?

Comment: If it is a simple configuration you can do it this way: If you have for example three questions and want to answer the first two with y and the third with n , you want to use `printf "y\ny\nn\n" | sudo apt-get install redmin`

Answer (score 1):

there is nothing to do with chef directly, but rather with the package manger of the operating system.

from your post it is clear that you are using [*debian*](https://www.debian.org/) or one of its derivative, such as [*ubuntu*](https://www.ubuntu.com/), due to the use of [`apt`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt). `apt` actually leverages [`dpkg`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dpkg)... so to make your installation smooth, you will have to tell both `apt` and `dpkg` to run non-interactively.

i would have post here a short snippet of the solution, but i rather lead you to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866431/apt-options-within-configuration-files)

Comment: I found out I have to create a debconf seed file like this one: https://github.com/kohana/chef-redmine/blob/master/templates/default/debconf-redmine.seed.erb Do you known how can I find all possible options?